# Laravel issue in join query

Tags: php, laravel

here is my code

```
return DB::table('jobs')->Join('cities','jobs.city_id','=','cities.city_id')
                             ->select('jobs.city_id', DB::raw('COUNT(jobs.city_id) AS num_jobs'))
                             ->groupBy('jobs.city_id')
                             ->orderBy('cities.city')
                             ->limit($limit)
                             ->get();
```

I want to get result order by alphabetically cities name which is in cities table row name as city and city_id in both tables jobs and cities, I also want number of jobs to show number of jobs in a specific city.
Thanks,

Comment: Describe your issue in join query. didn't you get correct response or any other error are you gettiing ??

Comment: didn't get any response, just error blade

Answer (score 0):

Change `strict` value to `false` in database.php file. It will works.

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => false,  //Change this
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

Comment: thanks a lot,, working well now, but speed  slow on browsing

Comment: @ljaz Ahmad Speed issue is not because of this changes. may be connection issue or anything else.

Comment: sorry sir, but without this this change speed is well as was before